# how to reslove linkage error when running the application in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

As i am working MaintainJ to trace our application to create UML diagrams automatically. I deployed MaintainJ.war and our application.war into web apps and started using MaibntainJ application , at some point i have to set JVM properties for MaintainJ in tomcat using set JAVA_OPTS which i did but getting following exception when i start the tomcat and stuck with setting jvm properties in tomact.

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
15:35:27.952 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [v_1_0/applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1091) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1830) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure"
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at com.maintainj.aspect.ExecutionDataAspect.ajc$around$com_maintainj_aspect_ExecutionDataAspect$1$7d7905cdproceed(ExecutionDataAspect.aj:70) ~[MaintainJAgent.jar:1.8.6]
        at com.maintainj.aspect.ExecutionDataAspect.ajc$around$com_maintainj_aspect_ExecutionDataAspect$1$7d7905cd(ExecutionDataAspect.aj:71) ~[MaintainJAgent.jar:1.8.6]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:937) ~[db2jcc-4.18.60.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:292) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:356) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2306) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2289) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2038) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        ... 25 more
22-Feb-2017 15:35:28.046 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
22-Feb-2017 15:35:28.046 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/stouch-cms-services] startup failed due to previous errors
22-Feb-2017 15:35:28.077 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [stouch-cms-services] registered the JDBC driver [com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the J
DBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

can somebody help me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you have **aspectjrt.jar** or **aspectjweaver.jar** deployed in other of the applications in the same container as MaintainJ. MaintainJ agent already adds the classes in those jar files higher up in classpath.

Please remove aspectjrt.jar and aspectjweaver.jar file(s) from the other applications when you deploy your application with MaintainJ.

That would do it !